# What is wrong with the header location function in php

Tags: php

I have a php code that is meant to redirect people to a new page if they get the correct username and password. I have used a switch statement which has the header location function. The problem is that the header is executing for both cases and also the default keyword. I would only like the header to be excuted for one of the correct username and passwords

```
<?php 
switch($_POST["username"] + "|" + $_POST["password"]) {

case"un1"|"pw1":
    header("Location:http://MyFavWebsite.php");
break;

case"un2"|"pw2":
    echo "hello";
break;

default:
    echo "Go Away";
}
?>
```

I would like to know if this could be fixed i will appreciate any help to solve this problem.

Comment: header("Location:http://MyFavWebsite.php"); should be header("Location: MyFavWebsite.php");

Comment: `switch($_POST["username"] + "|" + $_POST["password"]) {` ?!?

Comment: remove the `""` which  surrounded `|`,it should be something like "un1|pw1" which would match the condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
case"un1"|"pw1":
```

Because that is not the right format for a string and it breaks your switch structure

```
case "un1|pw1":
```

Is.

And Oh someone might ask. That `|` is a bitwise `OR` operator and its result for your first case is `TRUE` that's why you always get that redirect.

Answer (score 1):

header has no issue but your switch syntax is wrong, use both parameters as one condition
i.e

```
<?php 
switch($_POST["username"].$_POST["password"]) {

case"un1pw1":
    header("Location:http://MyFavWebsite.php");
break;

case"un2pw2":
    echo "hello";
break;

default:
    echo "Go Away";
}


//e.g
$un='un1';
$pass='pw1';

switch($un.$pass) {

case"un1pw1":
    header("Location:http://MyFavWebsite.php");
break;

case"un2pw2":
    echo "hello";
break;

default:
    echo "Go Away";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change case"un1"|"pw1": to case "un1|pw1"